# how to resolve the swrevealviewcontroller issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used `SWRevealviewcontroller` in my project. At first I took a `viewcontroller` named it "**SWREVEALVIEWController**" and set the `sw_rear` to a `tableviewcontroller`. And  in the `sw_front` part I set a `TabbarViewcontroller`.

[image]

Now  I have the few row data in my `tableview` which i set as `sw_rear` .

```
menuArray = ["HOME","ORDER NOW","PHOTOS","REVIEWS","FEEDBACK","RATE US","LOGIN"]
```

And clicking on each particular cell i set it to the appropriate viewcontroller like this.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
    case 0 :
        print("1st row")
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Main", sender: self)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        case 1 :
        print("2nd row")
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UINavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuVC") as! UINavigationController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But After using this its going to the appropriate place but without its tabbar items.

see the screens . the first screen is

[image]

after clicking the side menu cells for example clicking on home the home viewcontrollers open but without its tabbar item. how to solve this??

[image]

[image]

And after that the sliding button for `swRevealviewcontromller` not working after returning back to any `viewcontroller` by clicking on cells menu...????

Comment: can you rename your view controller to another name?

Comment: yeah any name you can take @BashirSidani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `pushFrontViewController` method from SWRevealViewController to change your front view controller.

Example

```
self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

To push your TabbarViewcontroller, you should give it an identifier in the Storyboard. Then you can use

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourtabbarvcidentifier")
self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**EDITED**

To open a certain tab

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourtabbarvcidentifier") as! UITabBarController
vc.selectedIndex = 1 // Your index you want to open
self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

*I did not test this*

Comment: but bydefault it will  go to the first tabbar items. if by clicking on sw_rear cell rows i have to go to  2nd or 3rd tabbar item then??

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your SW_front ViewController

```html
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    
   if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

Comment: can you able to send in swift

Comment: I already have used it in viewWillAppear . but still  after returning back to the home menubutton action not working when ever i set segue from another page to this viewcontroller

Comment: use navigation controller for front view

Answer (score 0):

```
 let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourControllerIndentifire")
 let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller!)
 revealViewController()?.pushFrontViewController(nc, animated: true)
```